# VirtualBox with Linux Mint 13 Detects Wrong Drive Size

Tags: virtualbox, linuxmint

I am trying to install Linux Mint 13 on my VirtualBox.  I created a new VB hard drive with a dynamically allocated size of 8GB (I have tried with fixed size as well).  I have tried installing Linux Mint 13 64-bit and 32-bit and every time during install, it sees the hard drive size as 8.6GB (bigger than I made the drive to be) and if I proceed, after install it only sees the drive size as 4.5GB and of course fills up very quickly.

I am on a Windows 7 64-bit host OS with 8GB of memory (4GB which I have been allocating to the guest).  I didn't have any issues with install.  Everything goes smoothly until the drive size is shown in my guest.

What am I doing wrong?  Should I try an earlier version (I have already downloaded both architectures of 13)?

Comment: Boot with a bootable disc image like Ubuntu for example or RIP and run gparted and see what it reports as the disk size. And/or any utility of choice to see what the drive image size is being reported as.

Comment: GParted says 8GB, but even after creating a partition table on the disk, the installer still sees it as 8.6GB....bizarre.....still stumped

Comment: What does it say the partition table type and filesystem are?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was pretty simple.  I've never allocated this much memory to a VM before so it turns out that since I had 4GB of memory and told mint to take care of the partitioning itself, it used 4GB for the swap hence my 8GB turning into 4GB.  I made a new HD and allocated 12GB and now I have 8GB available after install.

**Side Note**
Still baffles me that Mint recognizes the drive as 8.6GB when it's really only 8GB, but nonetheless I got up and running.